# What is the FAA regulation for the 3 mile / 1,000' separation for a commercial airliner?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, separation

I need help finding the Number/Citation for the FAA regulation/order that states commercial airliner separation should usually be at least 3 miles laterally, ***or*** 1,000 feet vertically.

**I cannot find anything that clearly states the **"or"** part.**

Comment: The title states the minimum safe distance, so the question clearly isn't, "How much is the minimum safe distance between two planes in flight?"

Comment: @RyanMortensen: Check the top answer, covers the FAA regs and orders as req'd here. If an answer is to be copied, then it is eligible for duplicate voting.

Comment: The accepted answer on that question is very thorough, and gives exactly the references asked for in this question. When closed, this question is still searchable/findable, even though the answer will be one more click away. VTC as a dupe.

Comment: @RyanMortensen: The other question can benefit from a better title. I tried to make it more findable by adding tags (before this thread started). FWIW, separation as explained there, is not fixed for *all* situations, which is another way of saying a "blanket" *or* won't be found. It can be found in 5−9−6 though for simultaneous approaches. If the question here is specific about simultaneous approaches, then sure it is not a duplicate. Once OP reviews the dupe/not-dupe, he/she can refine the scope depending on what they need.

Comment: @ymb1 sounds good.  I just worry sometimes that I'm seeing valuable specifics indefinitely swept under the rug due to similar topics having been asked in the past.  I know this isn't the place for the discussion, so maybe I'll put a question on meta sometime. Thanks.